# Rails + AJAX: How do I change the text in a text_field input to the value of @shipping_address.name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have everything set up, where a click of a checkbox will fire a javascript function that makes an ajax call to a route that maps to a controller#action. The issue is that it's not escaping the embedded ruby.

This is my input tag:

```
<input id="address_name" type="text" value="sfsfsd" size="30" name="address[name]">
```

And this is the JS that fires off in my `clone_shipping_address.js` file:

```
$("#address_name").val("<%= @shipping_address.name =>");
```

Lets say my @shipping_address.name = "Edmund".
The issue is that when I click the checkbox, the text that shows in the the text field becomes `<%= @shipping_address.name =>` (literally), instead of `Edmund`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:** Your file extension is '.js', which means this file is supposed to use only Javascript.

**A solution:** You can use Ruby code with ERB / HAML. Depending on which one you use, rename your file `clone_shipping_address.js` with the corresponding extension in order to execute the ruby code inside this file:

```
clone_shipping_address.js
# should become
clone_shipping_address.js.erb
# or if using HAML
clone_shipping_address.js.haml
```

Comment: Never mind I got it. It was a syntax error on the closing `%>` tag. Everything works!! thanks!!